# Why Java Base64 decode returns unreadable characters

Tags: java, base64, decode

I have a public key that has been encoded with Base64, and I have been instructed to decode the given encoded string to get actual Public key that needs to be used for GPG encryption.

What I am doing is, I have used below code to decode the given string to get the actual Public key, but when I do it, I see some unreadable characters printed on Eclipse console.

```
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    class Test 
    {
        String encodedPK = "mQGi..../../"; //I mentioned dummy here, due to security reasons
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedPK);
        System.out.println(new String(decoded));
    }
    OUTPUT:- "qÕÍ•Èé™‘™Ì
```

Comment: Base64 decodes to ```byte[]```, ```byte[]``` is unreadable unless you encode it to something (e.g. Base64).

Comment: Thanks, but, how can I get the Public key out of it, they said, I can get it after decoding it with Base64.

Comment: There are methods to restore public key from ```byte[]```.

Comment: Ok, can you please point me to any of them ?

Comment: It looks like JDK does not support GPG, you need 3rd party libraries. (e.g. bouncycastle)

Comment: @DilipKumar `can you please point me to any of them` LMGTFY .. there are plenty of examples - find any and if you have trouble with it, then ask an exact question

Comment: I am not sure why people down vote to the questions they ask, we need to understand that, people come here only after running out of options they have, and they are getting blocked from asking another question, that's really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is, I used an online Base64 decoder tool to decode the encoded key and remaining things worked smooth. So, the issue was, I was not decoding properly.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a working base64 decoder.

A cryptography key is not made out of readable characters. It's made out of arbitrary bytes that aren't likely to be correctly displayed when trying to. That's why anyone would even imagine encoding a key to base64: the base64 is made out of text and can be exchanged easily through text-based communication.

After you've decoded your key from base64 to byte[], it is fully decoded. You have done the job of decoding it. Anything that tries to use such a key will be demanding a byte[], not displayable characters.